# Walkable sub matrix of a Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given the adjacency matrix of a graph $G$ with at least one cycle, is there a known analytical method to create a submatrix of walkable paths.

Def. A walkable path is a matrix with no leaves.

Example: $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 1&0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ has the following walkable subgraph $S=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 1&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ as it is impossible to "get stuck" and not be able to keep moving forward. - Walking onto a leaf would constitute "getting stuck"

An algorithmic approach could entail removing leaves until only cycles remain, I am interested in a direct analytical approach.

Thanks, Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like you to present to you a lame but working technique. You calculate $Q=A^n$, where $n$ is the size of the matrix. And then for every $i$-th zero row in $Q$, you set the $i$-th column in $A$ to zero.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That is still algorithmic to me in that you have to perform searches and change data. The answer doesn't just pop out of the maths if you will.

Comment: If you want formula, you may try $A'=A\mathop{\mathrm{sign}}(QQ^T)$